# Bulk Import into SQL server Table

Tags: sql-server

Can you please help me with the syntax to bulk import this data:

```
startIpNum,endIpNum,country,region,city,postalCode,latitude,longitude,dmaCode,areaCode
1.0.0.0,1.7.255.255,"AU","","","",-27.0000,133.0000,,
1.9.0.0,1.9.255.255,"MY","","","",2.5000,112.5000,,
1.10.10.0,1.10.10.255,"AU","","","",-27.0000,133.0000,,
1.11.0.0,1.11.255.255,"KR","","","",37.0000,127.5000,,
1.12.0.0,1.15.255.255,"CN","","","",35.0000,105.0000,,
1.16.0.0,1.19.255.255,"KR","","","",37.0000,127.5000,,
1.21.0.0,1.21.255.255,"JP","","","",36.0000,138.0000,,
1.22.0.0,1.23.255.255,"IN","","","",20.0000,77.0000,,
1.24.0.0,1.31.255.255,"CN","","","",35.0000,105.0000,,
1.33.0.0,1.33.255.255,"JP","","","",36.0000,138.0000,,
```

I am using this :

```
set quoted_identifier OFF
drop table #y
drop table #x
DECLARE @servername varchar(128),
@DatabaseName varchar(128), @filepath varchar(500), @pattern varchar(100), 
@TableName varchar(128),@query varchar(1000),@max1 int,@count1 int,@filename varchar(100),@fieldTerminator VARCHAR(100),@RowTerminator VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @servername ='SQL',
@DatabaseName ='Test',
 @filepath ='C:\test',
  @pattern ='*.*', 
@TableName ='WeeklyImport'
,@fieldTerminator='''","'''
,@RowTerminator='''"\n"'''
set @count1 =0
create table #x (name varchar(200))
set @query ='master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "dir '+@filepath+@pattern +' /b"'
insert #x exec (@query)
delete from #x where name is NULL
select identity(int,1,1) as ID, name into #y from #x 
drop table #x
set @max1 = (select max(ID) from #y)
--print @max1
--print @count1
While @count1 <= @max1
begin
set @count1=@count1+1
set @filename = (select name from #y where [id] = @count1)
set @Query ='BULK INSERT '+ @Tablename + ' FROM "'+ @Filepath+@Filename+'" 
                WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ' +@fieldterminator + ',ROWTERMINATOR = ' + @rowterminator + ')'
print @query
exec (@query)
end

drop table #y
```

Comment: Could you add some description and/or comments to your script so we would have some idea what/why you are doing. Also, point out what is part not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the SQL Import/Export tool in SQL Server?

[image]

For me, it's at `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe"`.  There's other SO pages on this, including [Questions about exporting and importing flatfiles (txt, csv) in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177860/questions-about-exporting-and-importing-flatfiles-txt-csv-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: I will need to do this using the BulkImport Process.
I know it will be easy using SSIS, but unfortunately I cannot use it for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out the following format file...

[image]

...against the first 3 columns of your csv file:

[image]

The query goes as follow:

[image]

You now only need to add all the other columns and specify their format inside the format file. You can use the `REPLACE` function if you need to modify some values before inserting them.

Comment: I was able to get them in just fine using this:

BULK INSERT mnIPBlocker.dbo.GeoIPCity_stage FROM 'D:\Test\Sample_Geo.csv'
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
 
Just need to know how I can get rid of the double-quotes around the country, region, city , postalcode cols

Comment: Sorry, I thought you didn't had that part working. I suppose running an update query against the imported data to remove the double-quotes is not an option, right?

Comment: Have you already tried to create a format file to describe the inserted data? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx

Comment: I updated my answer using now a specific format for every column. This way you can format every column as you wish.

Comment: @jdecuyper: The images in your answer seem to have disappeared. All I get is the message "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available. imgur.com".

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: I have sent a message to Imgur support in order to have these images back online, fingers crossed!